# Docker issue create directory

Tags: docker

I'm using a shell script that is trying to create a directory inside a container which is running. But it produces error as binary file not found.
Here is an example script:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -x
CONTAINER_ID=`docker ps | grep postgres | awk '{print $1}'`
docker exec -it $CONTAINER_ID bash mkdir /backup
```

Comment: Please add you bash file along with dockerFile.

Comment: Sorry that is not allowed this is a custom image

Comment: Then you should show your code to how you are creating directory.

Comment: We need details on your image, how did you build it, does it include bash? Also, please show the exact error message showing which binary is not found.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -x
CONTAINER_ID=`docker ps | grep postgres | awk '{print $1}'`
docker exec -it $CONTAINER_ID sh -c "mkdir /backup"
```

The `sh -c "mkdir /backup"` should work.

In case your docker image have `bash` inside it then try `bash -c "mkdir /backup"`

I tried from my end and got the desired result.

```
$ sh script.sh
+ docker ps
+ awk '{print $1}'
+ grep inspiring_sinoussi
+ CONTAINER_ID=08a35fa3c040
+ docker exec -it 08a35fa3c040 sh -c 'mkdir /backup'

$ docker exec -it 08a35fa3c040 sh
/ # ls / | grep backup
backup
```